# Showing $\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} X_n/n \leq 1$ for a sequence of random variables, $X_n$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

We are given that $X_n$ is non-negative and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X_n > n) < \infty $.

I defined $A_n = \{ \omega\in\Omega : \frac{X_n}{n} > 1\}$ and directly used the first Borel-Cantelli lemma to get $P(\text{lim sup} A_n) = 0$ and then tried to do some rearranging using continuity of probability but I could never get rid of the probability.

What I'm now trying is noting that $ \text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{n} \leq 1$ is logically equivalent to:

$P(\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{n} > 1) = 0$

$P(\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} A_n) = 0$.

In other words, the event $A_n$ does not happen infinitely often.
Then, by Borel-Cantelli, from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X_n > n) < \infty$ we get $P(\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{n} > 1) = 0$

$P(\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} A_n) = 0$.

Then since the $A_n$ does not happen infinitely many times, then $\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{n}\leq 1$.

I'm not sure if this works or if I got my definitions messed up. This seems too simple. When I first saw lim sup, I assumed I'd have to use the set limit definition.

If this is not valid, could anyone provide me with a hint? Also sorry for poor formatting.

Comment: It is correct but don't say $\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} X_n/n \leq 1$ ever. Say $\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} X_n/n \leq 1$ **with probability $1$** (or a.s.) .

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks! it seems as though i was overthinking it but I've convinced myself this is true now.